# Export array as an es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

For some reason I'm unable to use an array exported as an es6 module:

```
export const choices = [
  ['first', 'First'],
  ['second', 'Second'],
  ['third', 'Third'],
]
```

Then:

```
import { choices } from './constants'
console.log(choices) // undefined
```

If I simply declare the `const` in the same file where I'm trying to use it, it works as expected.

Comment: That code is just fine (other than relying on ASI :-) ), and works for me in Chrome (if I add `.js` to the import). What environment are you doing this in? Are you using some kind of bundler?

Comment: Is your problem happening on Jest?

Comment: You're right - adding `.js` fixes this. I'm using React via Facebook's create-react-app. My components, classes, functions and objects can all be imported without specifying the file extension.

Comment: Bizarrely, if I change the filename from `constants` to `helpers`, it works. Is `constants` a protected word in javascript or es6? I know `const` is, perhaps related..

Comment: @Toby - No, `constants` isn't protected in JavaScript itself. Perhaps something in your loader config, or you have some other `constants.x` file that has priority in your web server config. I'd've expected an error message in the web console rather than logging `undefined` in this case.

Comment: It's possible - oh well... TIL. @T.J.Crowder if you want to provide your comment an answer I'll check it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modules in browser contexts use relative URLs, including extension. So the import should be `from './constants.js'` rather than just `from './constants'`. (The latter would be fine on Node.js, though, with its currently-experimental modules support.)